dracut Warning: Duplicate address detected for 10.0.2.15 while doing dhcp. retrying
I'm trying to boot Linux from Google Drive as mentioned in the blog. so for that, I've compiled dracut and created initramfs in form of efi image as mentioned in the blog.
./dracut.sh --kver 6.9.6-arch1-1 \
    --uefi efi_firmware/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi \
    --force -l -N --no-hostonly-cmdline \
    --modules "base bash fuse shutdown network" \
    --add-drivers "target_core_mod target_core_file e1000" \
    --kernel-cmdline "ip=dhcp rd.shell=1 console=ttyS0"

all the above steps are done on an emulated x86 Ubuntu 22.04 in Mac m3.
Now I've installed qemu on Mac and I'm booting up the above-created efi image using the below command
qemu-system-x86_64 -bios ./OVMF.fd -m 2G -drive format=raw,file=fat:rw:./efi_firmware -netdev user,id=network0 -device e1000,netdev=network0 -nographic

which also boots fine and drops me into dracut shell. Once I'm in I run the commands as suggested in the blog but dhclient is giving me errors as
dracut Warning: Duplicate address detected for 10.0.2.15 while doing dhcp. retrying
dracut:/# ip link set eth0 up
dracut:/# [   75.083588] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX

dracut:/# dhclient eth0
dhcp: PREINIT eth0 up
dhcp: BOUND setting up eth0
arping: invalid option -- 'f'
ARPing 2.22, by Thomas Habets <thomas@habets.se>
usage: arping [ -0aAbdDeFpPqrRuUv ] [ -w <sec> ] [ -W <sec> ] [ -S <host/ip> ]
              [ -T <host/ip ] [ -s <MAC> ] [ -t <MAC> ] [ -c <count> ]
              [ -C <count> ] [ -i <interface> ] [ -m <type> ] [ -g <group> ]
              [ -V <vlan> ] [ -Q <priority> ] <host/ip/MAC | -B>
For complete usage info, use --help or check the manpage.
[   86.239583] dracut Warning: Duplicate address detected for 10.0.2.15 while doing dhcp. retrying
dracut Warning: Duplicate address detected for 10.0.2.15 while doing dhcp. retrying


I'm not able to find what is causing the issue. If anyone has any idea that would be a great help.
thanks in advance
also tried booting via vmlinuz and initrd image but same issue. I'm expecting to have an IP assigned  by qemu dhcp

I was using "ARPing 2.22, by Thomas Habets" later I removed it and installed "arping from iputils 20211215" in my Ubuntu machine and rebuilted the image which worked fine.
keeping this question as if someone else facing the same issue they don't spent time finding the root cause.
